# Def function python: raw_input not store

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I'm newbie in python. I'm study hard to know well how python work since I starting study in 2013 at college. Sorry, if little messy.

Let me showing my problem below.
I have some def function looks like:

```
def thread_1():
                a = input('Value UTS (100) = ')
                if a > 100:
                    print line2
                    d=raw_input('Dont higher than 100. Input y to repeat : ') 
                    d='y'
                    if d=='y' :
                        thread_1()
                    return a

def thread_2():
                b = input('Value UAS (100) = ')
                if b > 100:
                    print line2
                    d=raw_input('Dont higher than 100. Input y to repeat : ') 
                    d='y'
                    if d=='y' :
                        thread_2()
                    return b
def thread_3():                         
                c = input('Value Course (100) = ')
                if c > 100:
                    print line2
                    d=raw_input('Dont higher than 100. Input y to repeat : ') 
                    d='y'
                    if d=='y' :
                        thread_3()
def thread_4():                                                          
                value_total = a*50/100+b*30/100+c*20/100
```

and this my expression def into program list

```
if p==1:
            thread_1()
            thread_2()
            thread_3()
            thread_4()
```

Finally, I running this program :
As long as I input number is well, but in the end program showing the error code like that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ganjil-genap.py", line 71, in <module>
    thread_4()   File "ganjil-genap.py", line 36, in thread_4
    value_total = a*50/100+b*30/100+c*20/100 NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Can anyone let me know what I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not passing `a` to `thread_4` (nor `b`, nor `c`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables a,b and c you are using on thread_1, thread_2 an thread_3 are only defined inside those functions. 'a' is only defined inside thread_1, b inside thread_2 and c inside thread_3, but theay are not global variables of the main program. The statement

```
return a
```

returns only the value of variable a.

you should make the vaiables global. I think it should look like this:

```
a=0
def thread_1():
   global a
   a= raW_input....
```

this will make your a,b,c variables global.

Then in thread_4() a,b and c should be passed as a parametres of the function.

```
def thread_4(a,b,c):
```

I think this should work.

Comment: No, you don't want to use `global`. The call should look like `a = thread_1()`.

Comment: Hey all thanks a lot for helping me. Matthias, however it's works, buds. ;)... I put 'global' in my source code. Thx juan I owe you :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the parameters to the `thread_*` functions.

For example, the `thread_4` function declaration need to look like this:

```
def thread_4(a, b, c):                                                          
    value_total = a*50/100+b*30/100+c*20/100
```

Also you have to give the arguments to your functions in the function call, for example:

```
if p==1:
    a=1, b=2, c=3   
    thread_1(a, b, c)
    thread_2(a, b, c)
    thread_3(a, b, c)
    thread_4(a, b, c)
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but is still error :
TypeError: thread_4() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)

Comment: In your function call, you have to give 3 arguments to the `thread_4` function. For example `thread_4(1, 2, 3)`. I edited my post for further explications.

Comment: I still confuse, I have done with your instruction :
thread_4(a, b, c)

Program Showing = NameError: name 'a' is not defined

.However, these method can works if i gave (a=80,b=90,c=20) example.. but it's static, how i load value from input 'a' (b or c) before?

Comment: Don't be confused :). I edited my post. Tell me if that fixes your problem.